# useState: setState behaving weirdly in StrictMode

Tags: reactjs

I have set the most basic of examples, a Todo List
When i click on the Done button for the first time, it works as expected: the todo item is marked as done: true, and "firing" and "setting" fires only once.
From then on, any button I click triggers the event once but "setting" runs twice so the done state returns to the previous state.

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-hermann-m53xs9

This only happens in StrictMode. I understand what StrictMode means but only regarding useEffect guarding, i had never encountered this behaviour before.

I need to understand why this is happening and how to prevent it.

```js
const TodoList = ({ allTodos }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(allTodos)

  const toggleTodo = id => () => {
    console.log('firing')
    setTodos(prev => {
      console.log('setting')
      const newTodos = [...prev]
      const todo = newTodos.find(todo => todo.id === id)
      todo.done = !todo.done
      return newTodos
    })
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <TodoComponent key={todo.id} todo={todo} toggle={toggleTodo(todo.id)} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const TodoComponent = ({ todo, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <li className={todo.done ? 'todo-done' : ''} key={todo.id}>
      <span>{todo.text}</span>
      <button onClick={toggle}>done</button>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't know why but when I use my usual way its working though https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-flower-r5y6dw?file=/src/App.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development) tells why double rendering happens in strict mode:

> React assumes that every component you write is a pure function. This means that React components you write must always return the same JSX given the same inputs (props, state, and context).

> If a function is pure, running it twice does not change its behavior because a pure function produces the same result every time. However, if a function is impure (for example, it mutates the data it receives), running it twice tends to be noticeable (that’s what makes it impure!) This helps you spot and fix the bug early.

> Components breaking this rule behave unpredictably and cause bugs. To help you find accidentally impure code, Strict Mode calls some of your functions (only the ones that should be pure) twice in development. This includes:
>
> - Functions that you pass to useState, set functions, useMemo, or useReducer

According to last quote, your function that you passed to `setState()` called twice. You can change your function like this for changing todos once:

```js
const toggleTodo = (id) => () => {
  setTodos((prev) => {
    const newTodos = prev.map((todo) =>
      todo.id === id ? { ...todo, done: !todo.done } : todo
    );
    return newTodos;
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I know that it works this way, i had tried it before. I need to understand why it happens when i run the other way as, for many recommendations, when the state derives from the previous state, we should use the setState with the callback version

Comment: Because of spreading an array returns shallow copy for objects like yours. In my updated code according to your comment for using `setState()` with callback version, it uses new array for your previous state using `map()`

Comment: it also works with  `const newTodos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev))`. the function runs twice as well but the result is what expected